# Reading in a list of strings in F# and minpulating the string

Tags: string, list, sorting, f#

This is my first venture of F# and after reading hours of language reference data on microsofts website I have attempted to come up with a simple program that reads a string into a list, sorts it alphabetically, and then reverses that list.

what I have so far:

```fs
[<EntryPoint>]
let peoplelist = []
printfn "Enter a Name or null to end:"
 let mutable looping = true
    while looping do
      let x= System.Console.ReadLine();
      let peoplelist = x :: peoplelist
      if x = "null" then
         looping <- false

printfn "%A" peoplelist
 let sortedpeoplelist = List.sort
printfn "%A" sortedpeoplelist
 let revpeoplelist = List.rev
printfn "%A" revpeoplelist
```

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can actually start learning some real code?

Comment: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ <- go this way ;)

Comment: Requests for offsite resources are off-topic for StackOverflow.  The resource suggested by @scrwtp is a much better place to start.  You could also checkout fsharp.org .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix would be to do:

```
let mutable peoplelist = []
    printfn "Enter a Name or null to end:"
    let mutable looping = true
    while looping do
        let x= System.Console.ReadLine();

        if x = "null" then
            looping <- false
        else
            peoplelist <- x :: peoplelist
```

the main problem is that

```
let peoplelist = x :: peoplelist
```

defines a new variable called `peoplelist` inside the while loop, which is different to the one declared at the top level. You probably also don't want to add a `null` to the list if entered by the user.

A better solution would be to avoid using mutable variables. You could define a function to continuously read lines from the console and keep reading until "null" is entered e.g.

```
let rec consoleLines = seq {
    yield System.Console.ReadLine()
    yield! consoleLines
}

[<EntryPoint>]
printfn "Enter a Name or null to end:"
let peoplelist = consoleLines |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> s <> "null") |> List.ofSeq
```